# Limits SetSysColor to one application

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mfc, gdi

I want to change the set of colors used in my software. My research led me to the [`SetSysColor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms724940.aspx) function. The problem with this function is that every software on the computer gets affected by the modification, not only the executable I want to modify.

Is there a way, or a alternative, to change the set of colors used by my application without having to redraw everything manually?

Comment: You could use a theming library

Comment: sadly It's not an option for me

Comment: Roll up your sleeves then and custom paint your app.

Comment: If you use the MFC Feature Pack, you can implement a custom `CMFCVisualManager` derived class. You will need to do some things by hand, but it is the easiest way I know to date. In http://i.imgur.com/bPVkiW1.png you can see a test image that is a proof-of-concept using the approach I mentioned on a real application.

Comment: Just...don't. There is no benefit in changing the colors of your application. You'll end up with something ugly that the user cannot customize when it is not to their liking (or not accessible for whatever reason). Leave it alone. Doing the right thing is usually easier than doing the wrong thing. This is a good example of that time.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases using custom colors may indeed be beneficial (highlighting, notifications, color-coding etc); just don't overdo. There are certain ways in WinAPI (usually accessible in MFC too - through events or direct WIndows message handlers) that let customize the appearance of your application. Look into the documentation for own-drawn controls, custom control colors, WIndows Class brushes, messages like WM_CTLCOLOR and WM_ERASEBKGND, You can also customize the looks of a window's non-client area (eg title-bar, borders etc), although this changes the appearance of your app a lot more drastically. See messages like NC_PAINT and NC_HITTEST.